# Moving program to /opt to make it accessible to all users?

Tags: permissions, appimage, opt

I use a program that is saved in my `/home/vincent/Downloads` directory (program is actually a game, I downloaded it...AppImage file), I normally start the program by double-clicking on it...
Now I would like this program to be available to all users.

Is it correct that I just need to move the AppImage file to e.g. `/opt` and give all users the permissions to execute the AppImage file ?
Would `chmod 1` be enough permissions?

I could also download the program into each user's home but that seems wrong...

Comment: You didn't provide OS/release details; but for my non-corporate desktops, I usually put my global executables in `/usr/local/bin/` as that directory is empty on new installs (*thus anything in it I put there*), is already in the $PATH for systems I use (*thus no changes required*). Of course if using a corporate/enterprise system - I follow site policies on where files get placed.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it correct that I just need to move the AppImage file to e.g.
> `/opt`

Correct except `/opt` is not in the default path of all users, but `/usr/local/games` is and seems the right place for your purpose.

> ... and give all users the permissions to execute the AppImage file ?
> Would "`chmod 1`" be enough permissions ?

You mean `chmod 111 file` ... No, users will also need the reading permissions set as well i.e. `chmod 555 file` is the minimum for what you want unless all the users are in the same group as the owner of the file where in this case `chmod 550 file` will suffice.

**Notice** according to [`man chmod`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/chmod.1.html) "*Omitted digits are assumed to be leading zeros*" ... Therefore, taking what you wrote literally, `chmod 1` will actually translate to `chmod 001` denying all permissions from owner `user:group` and leaving executable permissions for anyone else ... I already assumed you didn't mean to do that, but if you indeed meant to deny all permissions from the owner user and group, then the minimum for you is `chmod 5 file` or more explicitly `chmod 005 file` which will allow, ironically, only `Others` to execute the file.

Comment: Generally for /opt/ you have an executable you need to link to file in PATH. Or start an systemd service.

Comment: @Rinzwind I've also seen /opt/bin added to paths before

Comment: @NonnyMoose you are old skool? :D that got discarded for easier to maintain methods

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm not, but the people who did it certainly were.